# Link Click Delay in jQuery mobile 1.4.0

Tags: jquery-mobile

In my jQuery mobile app  , I have  3 pages each one is in a separate Html file Home Page -->Page1 contains Form To submit --> Page 2  , when I click the Page1 link from home Page it takes 4-5 seconds after clicking it  to open and show Page1 .

In Page2 I have a code for controlling the mobile device back button so when user click the device back button at page2 the app back to the home page directly without passing throw the Form Page "Page1", after back to the home Page if i click on Page1 link it will open and show Page1 directly zero  delay , This code has  increased the performance of jQuery and make the click speed as native apps ,but this happens  when i click Page1 link directly  after back from Page2. Then the delay returns .

I don't know How and why this piece of code has increased the performance,and because its very annoying to the users to wait 4 seconds after clicking the button then open the Page ,I have tried to apply  the same way when I navigate to Page1 in order to increase the click speed , but it didn't work ! the delay still .  Any one  can know why the code of controlling device back button has increased the speed ?

Please help me ..

Code for controlling device back button in Page2

```
    $(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {

       if (data.toPage && data.options.fromPage) {
          var _from = data.options.fromPage[0].id;
          var _to = data.toPage[0].id;
          if (_from === "page2" && _to === "FormPage") {
             $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "Home.html");
              e.preventDefault();
               }
          }
      });
```

Home Page

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>Header - Home</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
    <a href="FormPage.html" data-transition="none"  class="ui-btn"  data-         role="button">Page1</a>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>Footer</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

FormPage.html

```
 <!-- Page 1 -->
 <div data-role="page" id="FormPage">
     <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>Header - Page 1</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
     <form>
     // form elements 
     <div   class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-icon-check " >                                                   
        <input type="button" id="submit" data-inline="true" value=" submit"    data-iconpos="left" />

      </div> 
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>Footer</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

Home.js  // What I have tried to increase the click speed

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data)
{

  if (data.toPage && data.options.fromPage) {
    var _from = data.options.fromPage[0].id;
    var _to = data.toPage[0].id;
    if (_from === "Home" && _to === "FormPage") {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "FormPage.html");
        e.preventDefault();
    }



});
```

Comment: have you tried adding `data-prefetch` to anchor link? `<a href="FormPage.html" data-transition="none" data-prefetch>`?

Comment: @OmarYes I have tried it before ,but it didn't  affect the speed , and the form validation becomes not working

Comment: @OmarWhen your code of back button performed , a magic added to the home page and when i click the link the delay becomes zero , but this magic stay for 1 minute after back from Page2 !,I have tried to apply the same way for links but it didn't work for me . Please can you help me I have spend 1 day  in searching and trying to solve this issue but it not solved :( its very very important to solve this problem , please I will appreciate any help

Comment: One possible way is prefetch pages and keep then DOM. JQM removes external pages once you navigate away. Add `data-dom-cache="true"` to all page divs.

Comment: @OmarIhave tried it , it increases the speed , but there is a problem if i open the form and type some data in the input fields then back to home , and again open the formPage  all the previously entered data remains in the form

Comment: @OmarHow can we solve this problem ??can you help me more please?

Comment: Wipe data before visiting the page. `$("#form").trigger("reset")` to show default values. If not a form, you should go through elements and reset them manually.

Comment: @OmarIhave tried $("#form").trigger("reset") and it didnt work for me , and also in the pageinit event for the FormPage i have called a ResetForm() function in which i did: $('#NameInput').attr('value',""); but it didn't work , I have tried many times and many ways but i failed to make it work :( please is there any wrong in the way i reset the input field ?

Comment: `pageinit` fires once per page, use `pagebeforeshow`.

Comment: @OmarThanks a lot  its working now ,cashing Pages is the only possible sol for speeding up click ?? there is no other possibilities??

Answer (score 0):

The reason the back button navigation is so much faster i preloading. It's already loaded and just needs to be displayed.

You can manual preload pages by using

```
$.mobile.loadPage( "YourPage" );
```

I outline a few different methods of speeding up transitions in jQuery mobile here: [Speeding up page transitions in jQuery Mobile 1.1 for iPhone apps built with PhoneGap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024464/speeding-up-page-transitions-in-jquery-mobile-1-1-for-iphone-apps-built-with-pho/11027381#11027381)
Even though the query mobile version specified in the answer is dated, the solutions are not.

EDIT: Wanted help in the comments:

To use energize.js just include it BEFORE loading jQuery or jQuery mobile. Get it here: https://github.com/davidcalhoun/energize.js

Preloading components in hidden divs is a hacky way to force jQuery mobile to load components it doesn't currently need. Just put the components you use on page 2 but not on page 1 within a hidden div like so:

```
<div style=display:none> //COMPONENTS HERE </div>
```

Comment: @HessiusThanks for help , These method I already using them in my app , and $.mobile.loadPage( "YourPage" ); I have tried it before  it  didn't enhance the performance to zero delay

Comment: No you will probably not reach zero delay. Try preloading components in hidden divs. E.g. If your second page uses form elements and your first page doesn't. Add a hidden div with form elements to the first page, that way those modules will already have been loaded further increasing performance

Comment: Also since you're using a href, use something like energize.js or bind the changepage event to tap on the link, that will shave off approx. 300 ms

Comment: How can i do this? can you give me an example since I am new in jQuery mobile.. but after clicking device back button and performing the code for the back button , the delay become zero  , and the click speed become as native apps

Comment: Yes that's because everything is loaded already. Which of the techniques mentioned above did you need help with?

Comment: Ok , but when i click device back button from Page1  to back to Home Page ( page1 didn't contain code for controlling the device back button ) and again i click page1 link it takes 4 seconds to show Page 1 even if it loaded before

Comment: Were there any of the techniques you needed help with?
BTW check the query mobile api: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-load
They now recommend using load instead of loadpage as it is deprecated in 1.4.0

Comment: energize.js for what is used?  is like fast click.js for eliminate the 300ms ?

Comment: can you help me in this :  preloading components in hidden divs ,and energize.js

Comment: Yes, energize.js is like fast click except you don't need to bind energize to any element, id automatically speeds up all elements

Comment: Thanks I will try it, how can i do this preloading components in hidden divs ??can you give me an example please?

Comment: Thanks a lot i have tried energize.js but it didn't increase the performance , it still take 4 seconds to show Page1 even if i have used touchstart , tap event on <a> element , I will try the second solution: Preloading components in hidden divs  and i hope this will speed up the code

Comment: Ok, if you feel the answer was helpful please up vote and or select it as the correct answer

Comment: I have tried it , unfortunately it also didn't work :(

Comment: Also you should probably switch to a single multipage file instead of several html files. With the techniques mentioned here and in the linked post, you will without a doubt shave of a bit of your loading time, with that said. It probably won't be 0. Ever.

Comment: @HessiusThanks for your help,Its very difficult  for me to switch to a single multipage file since I have developed half of my app in multiHtml files approach , and  Certainly your answer is usefull and can be work for those who are using a single multipage file, and i really appreciate your help